# Existence of an Isometry

Tags: linear-algebra

**Suppose $T_1,T_2$ are normal operators on $L(F^3)$ and both operators have $2,5,7$ as eignevalues. Prove that there exists an isometry $S$ such that $T_1=S^*T_2S$.**

I know that since they have the same eigenvalues, then they're Diagonal matrix is the same. Also, since they are normal, there exists a unitary diagonalization.

I'm not sure how to prove this because I know that the Unitary matrix is an isometry.

Comment: May I suggest that if your question has been adequately answered, you up-vote and accept the answer. It is a polite way to express your appreciation to someone who has made the effort to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure where the gap in your understanding is; all the pieces of the proof seem to be in your question.

There exists a diagonal matrix $D$ and unitary matrices $S_1,S_2$ such that
$$
T_1 = S_1DS_1^* \\
T_2 = S_2DS_2^* \implies
D = S_2^*T_2S_2 $$
We may now substitute
$$
T_1 = S_1DS_1^* = S_1(S_2^*T_2S_2)S_1^* = 
[S_2 S_1^*]^*T_2[S_2S_1^*]
$$
It follows that $S = S_2S_1^*$ is a valid such isometry.

Comment: I just wasn't sure it could be that simple

Comment: I find that when you have that question about a textbook problem, the answer is usually *yes*.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, Are $T_1, T_2$  self-adjoint? Since there are three distinct eigenvalues for $T_1$ and $T_2,$ and the dimension of $\mathbb{F}^3$ is 3, I guess that the two normal operators are actually self-adjoint.

Comment: @azc indeed: a normal matrix with real eigenvalues is necessarily self-adjoint. Doesn't affect the proof, though.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: Thanks. I just found a result in Axler's book Linear Algebra Done Right: Prove that a normal operator on a complex inner product space is self-adjoint if and only if all its eigenvalues are real.